# Create Dynamic class with specific parameter for each methods

Tags: python, class, methods, dynamic

I would like to create a dynamic method in a Class but with specific docstring and parameters for each method. I understand the process to create a dynamic method but I don't know how to create my specific parameters and my docstring

I write this :

```
class Test_Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'Test'

def my_new_method(self, a) -> str:
    """
        Something ...

    Args:
        a ([type]): [description]

    Returns:
        str : [description]
    """
    headers = []
    name_params = ''
    return str(a)


for i in ['test_A', 'test_B']:
    setattr(Test_Class, i, my_new_method)

Foo().test_A(54)
```

And I would like to have this format :

```
class Test_Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'Test'
    def test_A(self, a):
        """
            Test A

        Args:
            a ([type]): [description]

        Returns:
            str : [description]
        """
        headers = [1,2,3,4]
        name_params = 'Something'
        return str(a)
    def test_B(self, a):
        """
            Test B

        Args:
            a ([type]): [description]

        Returns:
            str : [description]
        """
        headers = [57,218,78,6]
        name_params = 'Another'
        return str(a)
```

Comment: Where do the different headers and name params come from?

Comment: The best way for me, is to set this params during the loop

Comment: Are you just trying to parameterize a single test? `pytest`, for example, provides `pytest.mark.parameterize`

Comment: It's not for a test

Comment: I think passing header the headers and name parameter to `Test_Class.__init__`, then creating multiple instances that all use the same single method `test` would make more sense than creating a bunch of distinct methods that differ only in hard-coded internal values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html):

```
class MyNewMethod:
    def __init__(self, headers, params):
        self.headers = headers
        self.params = params

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.public_name = name  # "test_A, test_B"

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        def func(a):
            # a: method parameter
            # obj: instance the method is called on (aka self)
            # self: descriptor instance with access to custom params/headers
            return str(obj.a) + str(a) + str(self.headers) + str(self.params)
        func.__doc__ = "super dynamic stuff using " + self.public_name
        # more mimicking:
        # func.__name__ = self.public_name
        # func.__qualname__ = f"{objtype.__name__}.{self.public_name}"
        return func

class _Base:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

Now you can create dynamic classes with attributes using the descriptor class (attaching the attribute via `setattr` does not call the `__set_name__` hook):

```
A = type("A", (_Base,), {"test": MyNewMethod(3, 4)})

a = A(1)
a.test(2)
# 1234

help(A.test)
# ...
# test(a)
#     super dynamic stuff using test
```